Error While using Redux - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'items')
I'm trying to access states from the redux store using useSelector(), but instead I get the following error-

AddToCart.jsx:7 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'items')
    at AddToCart.jsx:7:58
    at react-redux.js?v=afc4f5cf:189:28
    at memoizedSelector (react-redux.js?v=afc4f5cf:46:38)
    at getSnapshotWithSelector (react-redux.js?v=afc4f5cf:74:22)
    at mountSyncExternalStore (react-dom_client.js?v=afc4f5cf:11886:28)
    at Object.useSyncExternalStore (react-dom_client.js?v=afc4f5cf:12573:22)
    at useSyncExternalStore (chunk-4HAMFFQC.js?v=afc4f5cf:1120:29)
    at useSyncExternalStoreWithSelector3 (react-redux.js?v=afc4f5cf:81:23)
    at useSelector2 (react-redux.js?v=afc4f5cf:243:27)
    at AddToCart (AddToCart.jsx:7:19)


store.js
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import itemcountSliceReducer from './itemcountSlice'

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    itemcountSliceReducer,
  }
})

export default store;

itemcountSlice.js
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialState = {
  items: {
    1: 0,
    2: 0,
    3: 0,
    4: 0,
    5: 0,
    6: 0,
    7: 0,
    8: 0,
    9: 0,
  },
  totalAmount: 0,
}

const itemcountSlice = createSlice({
  name: "itemcount",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    addItem: (state, action) => {
      state.items = {
        ...state.items, 
        [action.payload.id]: state.items[action.payload.id] + 1
      }
    },
    rmvItem: (state, action) => {
      state.items = {
        ...state.items, 
        [action.payload.id]: state.items[action.payload.id] - 1
      }
    }
  }
})

export const { addItem, rmvItem } = itemcountSlice.actions;
export default itemcountSlice.reducer;

AddToCart.jsx
import React from 'react'
import { useSelector,useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import {addItem} from '../store/itemcountSlice'

const AddToCart = ({ id }) => { 
  const count = useSelector((state) => state.itemcount.items[id])
  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  return (
    <button onClick={(e) => dispatch(addItem(id))}>
      <img
        src = '../../assets/images/icon-add-to-cart.svg'
        alt = 'add to cart'
      />
      <span>Add to Cart</span>
    </button>
  )
}

export default AddToCart

App.jsx
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import './App.css'
import cardsData from '../data.json'
import Card from './components/Card'

function App() {
  const data = cardsData.map((item, i) => (
    { ...item, id: i + 1 }
  ))

  return (
    <div className='main-container'>
      <div className='left-container'>
        <h1>Desserts</h1>
        <div className='cards-container' >
          {data.map((item) => 
            (<Card image = {item.image.desktop}
                category = {item.category}
                name = {item.name}
                price = {item.price} 
                key = {item.id} 
                id = {item.id}           
            />))}
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className='right-container'></div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App

My App component is wrapped in a Provider tag, so I'm not sure what the problem is. Is there a syntax issue when I'm using useSelector, or have I not added the reducers to the store in the correct manner.

state.itemcount.items[id] - It would appear that there is no itemcount on state.  Should there be?

hey Aviral, you need to return a new state back from the reducer functions, also in your case don't mutate the object

@David "itemcount" is the name I gave to the slice I created. From my understanding of redux-tlk, you need to give the slice name followed by the state you're fetching, in this case state.itemcount.items[id]. This was my understanding of it, not sure if I'm correct though

@YashJoshi From my understanding, Redux-toolkit allows to write such code in the reducer functions which looks like we're mutating the state, but doesn't act as such. It allows us to omit the return function as well. But maybe my execution is wrong?

Oh interesting I didnt know that, although I did check their example they were returning the values

Issue
You are selecting from state.itemcount but this Redux state property does not exist since you named it itemcountSliceReducer when creating the store.
const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    itemcountSliceReducer, // <-- state.itemcountSliceReducer
  }
})

Solution
The state you are creating must match the state you are selecting.
Either rename the root state to itemCount like you are selecting:
const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    itemCount: itemcountSliceReducer, // <-- state.itemcount
  }
})

const count = useSelector((state) => state.itemcount.items[id]);

Or update the selector function to match the root state identifier:
const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    itemcountSliceReducer, // <-- state.itemcountSliceReducer
  }
})

const count = useSelector((state) => state.itemcountSliceReducer.items[id]);

Suggestion/Improvement
Unrelated, but you'll also want to get into the habit of creating memoized selectors for the id value you are using in the selector function.
Example:
import { createSelector } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const selectItemCounts = (state) => state.itemcount.items;

const selectItemCountById = createSelector(
  [
    selectItemCounts,
    (state, id) => id,
  ],
  (items, id) => items[id]
);

const count = useSelector((state) => selectItemCountById(state, id);

You also don't need to shallow copy the states, you can directly mutate them if you like since RTK utilizes Immer.js under-the-hood, i.e. it handles the shallow copying of the draft changes to the next state value.
Example:
const itemcountSlice = createSlice({
  name: "itemcount",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    addItem: (state, action) => {
      state.items[action.payload.id]++;
    },
    rmvItem: (state, action) => {
      state.items[action.payload.id]--;
    }
  }
})

